# Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread

Tags: xcode, parse-platform, xcode6.1

The warning happen when I am using parse. I tried with more than one App. The App take too long to launch. Is this normal?

Warning: A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread.
Break on warnBlockingOperationOnMainThread() to debug.

Comment: It sounds like you're executing a blocking Parse.com function in the app delegate. 
You should use the non-blocking variant. Can you post your delegate code?

Comment: I get the same error. This is my delegate code.

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch            
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore()
        Parse.setApplicationId("xx", clientKey: "xx")
        PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebook()
        println("Application Launched")
        return true
    }

I looked at some of the answers here. But cannot get it working. Any help is much appreciated.